# How to redirecting domain on route53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have a domain name xyz.com which was redirecting to abc.com at Godaddy. I have migrated to route53 then it started working fine including the redirection to abc.com. But I want to redirect xyz.com to 123.com now. I did not find any option on route53 to do this task. Please suggest.

Comment: You have to configure a CNAME Record from xyz.com to 123.com

Comment: I have created cname for www.xyz.com as www.123.com. But I am not seeing affect when I use xyz.com. I can see www.xyz.com is getting redirected to 123.com. Please help to redirect http & xyz.com to 123.com. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you redirect from one toplevel domain to another using Route53](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29669779/how-do-you-redirect-from-one-toplevel-domain-to-another-using-route53)

Comment: From the official documentation you can see an example: https://aws.amazon.com/de/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-domain-route-53/